# Varnish 4 is retrying the backend request every 120 seconds continuously

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-4

Varnish 4 is retrying the request every 120 seconds continuously if the corresponding backend endpoint is taking more than 120 seconds. While the backend is retrying the request, the original varnish request is waiting. The original varnish request is not returning 503. All the other backend endpoints are responding within 1 minute. Default backend timeout and max-retries settings are used. No explicit request restarts are used in the vcl. The varnish version is [4.1.4](http://www.canonware.com/download/varnish/varnish-4.1.4.tar.gz)

Is it the expected behaviour or is it a bug? If it is a bug, how can it be mitigated?

Comment: Have you tried with the last 4.1 release ? When we are speaking it is 4.1.9 What is your timeout configuration ? Here some details on timeout https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/understanding-timeouts-varnish-cache

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by this bug: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/pull/2135

Varnish is supposed to retry once when using keepalive connections. But there was a bug in the logic and in some edge cases it retried infinite times.

Comment: I followed the link but could not find any workaround for it? Do you know any workaround?

Comment: No at the moment I don't know of any good workarounds. We have attempted to mitigate this for now by setting our timeouts lower the further in the stack you go. So the backend should always timeout before Varnish does, and stop Varnish from retrying.